# Warning: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [1] in phpservermonitor

Tags: server, php, lamp

Everytime I click on the **update** button in **phpservermonitor** it gives out this error:

> Warning: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [1]: Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/phpservermon/src/psm/Util/Server/Updater/StatusUpdater.php on line 154
>
> Warning: socket_set_option() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/phpservermon/src/psm/Util/Server/Updater/StatusUpdater.php on line 155

here is a file with all the errors it gives out, but the main one is that one, since most of the errors if not all are being caused by this one.

[**This is an image with all the errors**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2cec.png)
(I know shouldn't post pictures of errors, but I didn't want to make the post too big)

I went to the file in question in the first error, but could only figure out what the error already told me. That line 154 (the first line in the following code) **wasn't returning like it should**.

```
$socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 10, 'usec' => 0));
socket_connect($socket, $this->server['ip'], null);        
socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);
if (socket_read($socket, 255)) {
    $this->rtime =  microtime(true) - $starttime;
    $status = true;
} else {
    $status = false;
}
socket_close($socket);
```

**Tried going to php.ini and enabling sockets**, but it didn't change anything

the ; I removed at php.ini:

```
;extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
```

PS: I'm using **php5.6** and **ubuntu 18.04**, also if you think it's better that I write the whole list of errors just say that I'll edit the post.

Edit:
[Here is the phpinfo in which sockets are enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If4V7.png)

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out, you may need to enable the sockets extension. However, the way you did it is incorrect as you enabled an extension named `php_sockets.dll` which is only used for Windows installations of PHP.

*[DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) is a Windows implementation of shared library files.*

Instead, in Ubuntu, you enable an extension with the `phpenmod <module>` command.

For example, in your case, run the following command.

```
sudo phpenmod sockets
```

And restart (or reload) Apache for the change to take effect.

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. Do you know if there is any command with which I can check if sockets are enabled, that way I can check if that's the problem, or of course if you have any other clue of what it might be.

Comment: @PAPARIPA You can use [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and search the result for whether sockets are enabled, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRoWN.png.

Comment: I edited the post to show what you said and it's enabled. I really have no clue why this isn't working.